# Magento2: Insert and update operation in custom module Admin-side(through Admin panel)

Tags: magento2, database, admin

I have create a database-table.

I displayed(grid view with toolbar) the table-records in Admin-pannel.

Now I need to know the Insert,Updata and Delete process through admin-side process.Please Give any sample code's or Link...

Answer (score 1):

Create form using ui component

define datasource in di.xml and add Customdataprovider in form

please find below link to more:

https://www.pierrefay.com/magento2-training/form-component-backend-crud-admin.html

Answer (score 1):

**Using Ui-Componrnt :-**

[/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2](https://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can download module from github for custom grid in admin using ui component and change accordingly.

https://github.com/kirtinariya1/AdminGridUI